# Does this e-mail-regex exclude valid addresses?

Tags: regex, email, email-address

I tried to create a regular expression which catches *all* RFC-valid addresses but it's ok if some false-positives come through (though hopefully not so many). This is waht I came up so far:

```
/^\b\S+@\S+\.[^\s@]{2,}\b$/
```

Is there any RFC-valid address which doesn't match against this expression or do you have any suggestions to improve it? I don't mind the false positives but I would be glad if you show me a few, too.

Comment: If you really want a regex that does not reject valid addresses, use this one: `/.+/`

Comment: I was confident that this answer would come...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

E-mail addresses may contain nested comments, which kind of spoils most regex approaches. This is a valid e-mail address:

```
test(Oh (noes, an @) "sign")@(Here comes the domain)domain.com(TLD is com!!)
```

Even without comments, the local part may include quoted strings, which may contain whitespace.
The best approach I found is: look for an `@`. Thats mandatory. So I'd use

```
/.+@.+/
```

Answer (score 5):

Check out this post:

[Using a regular expression to validate an email address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-for-validating-email-addresses)

There is also this one:

http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html

Nothing like a 6000+ character regex!

Comment: He does not ask for a regex to match all and only all valid e-mail addresses.

Answer (score 3):

```
"foo bar"@example.com
```

The local part can contain spaces (they have to be quoted, but they are valid).

Answer (score 1):

```
name@[1.2.3.4]
```

doesn't match but is valid. A nice list of valid/invalid mail addresses for testing [can be found here](http://www.dominicsayers.com/isemail/results.php).

Answer (score 0):

Try regexbuddy to validate reqular expressions. Another handy website i often use is [regexplib](http://regexplib.com/Search.aspx?k=email)

Comment: I doubt the problem was trying out the RE but rather finding examples where it doesn't match ...